# pipenv --python 3.7 does nothing

Tags: python, pipenv

When I run

```
pipenv --python 3.7
```

it does:

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
```

when I run

```
pipenv --rm
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
You are attempting to remove a virtualenv that Pipenv did not create. Aborting.
Aborted!
```

So I'm unable to create or remove a virtual env

I'm using mac, and used homebrew to install python

Comment: "Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1"...

Answer (score 0):

From the error message:

> Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead.

we can see that Pipenv wasn't creating a new virtual environment because it discovered that you were already running it inside another virtual environment. Setting [`PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv.environments.PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS) will force it to still create another virtual environment even if it finds itself already running within one.